# How to add a height in the main container view according to its content? And others things

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

[image]

I'm starting with the design in iOS and it's complicated ...
I have various doubts:

1. The content of the center can be shown or not. Therefore, I need the height of the all main view to be reduced automatically. How can I do it?
   (In android is a wrap_content)
2. And conversely, how can I tell him that the main view is expended (match_parent)? This design (it is an advertisement) I charge it in other places, but it always has a fixed size and I would like it to adapt dynamically to the container.
3. In the case of the "BodyView" I want it to have a height min., max. and that by default grow by its content.
   If I add `lines = 0`, apparently all the content is seen.

Comment: Show the design that you are trying to implement.

Comment: For 1 and 2, you can use `autolayout` in `Xamain.iOS`. It's a relative layout and will resizing controls automatically after you set the right constraints. For more information, you can refer to [autolayout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/user-interface/designer/designer-auto-layout). For 3, you can specify a height to the label so that it will not grow by its content. Also you can calculate the height directly by the given text. `Autolayout` will also work if you set the height of label.